# A list in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, list

I'm trying to display a list in a lightning component : 
the component (Carousel.cmp)

```
<aura:component controller="CarouselController"  implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="actualites" type="Actualite__c[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.actualites}">
    {!a.Name} : {!a.Description__c}
</aura:iteration></aura:component>
```

the server side controller (CarouselController.apxc)

```
public with sharing class CarouselController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Actualite__c> getActualites(){
    List<Actualite__c> actualites = [select Id, Name, Description__c from Actualite__c];
    return actualites;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Actualite__c getActualite(Id id){
    Actualite__c actualite = [select Id, Name, Description__c from Actualite__c WHERE Id = :id];
    return actualite;
} }
```

the client side controller (CarouselController.js)

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getActualites");

    action.setCallback(this, function(reponse){
        if(reponse.getState === "SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.actualites", reponse.getReturnValue());
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
} })
```

I just try to display a dynamic list of Actualite__c but when I try to visualize it with my lightning application :

```
<aura:application >
<c:Carousel /></aura:application>
```

I just see a blank page...

Am I doing something wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: are you getting any error or something else?

Comment: no, I try to add a button in my component like that : `<ui:button label="yo !" press="{!c.doInit}"/>` ans i see the button in my page but nothing happen when i click it... (I comment the `aura:handler`)

Comment: Have you tried what Keith C suggested.. you need to change `a.getReturnValue()` to `reponse.getReturnValue()`.. If still facing issue then add a console.log `console.log(reponse.getReturnValue());` and check in browser console it is returning any value or not..

Comment: @Ratan use lightning inspector .Using inspector should help

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes lightning inspector is best.. Dou you can use this extension to debug the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check your aura:iteration.

In Your aura:repeat items you will need to use proper syntax {!v.actualites}

To debug download chrome extension for lightning inspector.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm

Also response.getState should be method not property .Correct syntax is response.getState()

Comment: I tried to use lightning inspector, when I see the action tab it say that the state of Action$getActualite is success... So that is what I want but I doesn't work...

Comment: Check all your variables as well that they are populated.Is your query returning rows?

Comment: How can I see if my query return rows ?

Comment: If I put a `debugger;` here : `({
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
  var action = component.get("c.getActualites");
  debugger;        
        action.setCallback(this, function(reponse){
            if(reponse.getState === "SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.actualites", reponse.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        
        console.log("reponse.getReturnValue()");
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
})` I see when debugging that it's not passing in the `action.setCallback(this, function(reponse){`

Comment: The method is response.getState() ..getState is method not oroperty

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot the () ! Well it solve my problem thank you so much ! But by the way I also learn how to use the debugging, and thanks for that too !

Comment: Mark the answer as answered so it helps others

Answer (score 3):

In an example I have, the argument to the callback function is where the return value came from:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
    component.set("v.contacts", actionResult.getReturnValue());            
});
```

In your code you have `a.getReturnValue()` instead of `reponse.getReturnValue()`.

You should check your browser's JavaScript console for errors; if the above is the cause you should see an error there such as "a is not defined".

Also this:

```
<aura:iteration var="a" items="v.actualites">
```

should be this:

```
<aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.actualites}">
```

Comment: Thank you I correct it. But my page is still blank ...

Comment: Then (assuming there are no other JavaScript errors in the console) I suggest you add some console.log calls to your JavaScript and some System.debug calls to your Apex to track down where the overall process is breaking.

Comment: @dou See the "Also this" addition.

Comment: I correct it thank you, but the problem remain the same... I don't see any error in the app.js in my browser, I try to use the deboger but I'm not feeling comfortable with it...

Comment: @dou I'm afraid you won't get very far unless you learn to use the debugging aids.